# Page break not working in dompdf with long text

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I have a problem with my code that page break is not working with long text. I wish that when the text is long, the text is available in a new page.

[image]

Here is the code I have tried:

```
 <h6 style="background: #cdcbcb; font-size: 13px; margin: 0px; padding:8px;">RENCANA KEPERAWATAN</h6>
        <table style="table-layout:fixed;" class='table table-bordered'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 30%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; text-align: center">No</th>
                    <th style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; text-align: center">Diagnosa Keperawatan</th>
                    <th style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; text-align: center">Tujuan</th>
                    <th style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; text-align: center;">Intervensi</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php $no=1; ?>

                @foreach ($data_rencanakeperawatan as $item)
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center">{{$no}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item->diagnosa_keperawatan_rencana}}</td>
                    <td>Setelah dilakukan intervensi keperawatan selama {{ $item->jam }} jam maka {{ $item->keterangan }} dengan kriteria hasil :
                    <?php 
                    $data_kriteria=DB::table('tb_kriteria')->where('id_rencanakeperawatan', $item->id_rencanakeperawatan)->get(); 
                    foreach ($data_kriteria as $value1) {
                    ?>
                        <p>• {{$value1->detail_luarankeperawatan}} ({{$value1->skor_kriteria}})</p>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php 
                        $data_intervensi=DB::table('tb_intervensirencana')
                        ->join('m_detailintervensi', 'tb_intervensirencana.id_detailintervensi', '=', 'm_detailintervensi.id_detailintervensi')
                        ->where('tb_intervensirencana.id_rencanakeperawatan', $item->id_rencanakeperawatan)->get(); 
                        $total_text=0; $jml_ket=0; $jml_intervensi=0; $jml=0;
                        foreach ($data_intervensi as $value2) {
                        ?>
                            <b>• {{$value2->keterangan}}{{$jml_ket}}</b><br>
                            {{$value2->dataintervensi}}{{$jml_intervensi}}<br>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php $no++; ?>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, It is said that **dompdf** do not create a *page break/new page* in table. Sad to say, you cannot do *next page line* when doing it on table. I also include on my comment that you can do a *line break/new page* on **div**. It make more complicated to do so, But I made this **[sample table on div that can handle long text and make new page](https://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php?identifier=c4fc2de18ebceb992937030e76f36057)**. 
You can start doing your project by referring to this scratch.

P.S.
**Dompdf** does not support making a new page using a table cells/rows between pages. Meaning if the text on your table is too long, it will move on the next page. Also all data inside the table will move also on the next page.

As I learn while doing a research, *DOMPDF* is rendering every element in your codes(1 elemen = 1 page). Since table is compose of (table,thead,tbody,tr,th & td), It will consider as one element.

As of now, *dompdf* is still not fixing this issue.
[reference #1](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2189)
[reference #2](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/pull/2512)

Comment: it's still error sir

Comment: how 'bout ```table{page-break-before: always;}```? If still not work, make div over your table or table over table and apply this *page-break-before: always;*. You can also check this [online debugger](https://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php) for designing dompdf.

Comment: `table{page-break-before: always;}` is working fine sir when short text column. but when the long text column, table page break column not working sir

Comment: Try *div over table* Sample (```<td><div>{{$item->diagnosa_keperawatan_rencana}}</div></td>```) then ```div{page-break-before: always;}```.  Or make a playground of your work so the problem can be checked easily.

Comment: I add `div{page-break-before: always;}` in my code. it's still error sir. 
where sholud I put my code in order you can check easily sir?

Comment: it's the example that I try in online sir. [online tester](https://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php?identifier=09864e579805cf3ff7fd16675b0e65bd)

Comment: Sorry I just to long for some research. I edited my answer.